# Why do other smoothers change when changing a particular smoother in gam?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm trying to understand mgcv::gam plot() output and probably by extension, gam theory.

In mgcv::gam(), I'm fitting smoothers to three (*a, b, c*) of my nine predictors for a particular model. (Whether this is a good model or not is irrelevant for the purposes of my question.)

I've found that once I change the arguments of the *smoother c* in s(...), all other things staying the same, *smoother a* and *smoother b* seem to be affected by this.

**Case 1: penalized reg. splines for a, b, and c.**

```
fit1<-gam(formula = x~s(a, fx=F)+ s(b, fx=F) + s(c, fx=F) +d+e+f+g+h+i, data=df)
```

1, 4.9, and 7.9 df estimated for a, b, and c respectively (based on CV)

[image]

**Case 2: penalized reg. splines for a and b, reg. spline with 3 df fixed for c**

```
fit2<-gam(formula = x~s(a, fx=F)+ s(b, fx=F) + s(c, fx=T, k=4) +d+e+f+g+h+i, data=df)
```

2.81 and 4.46 df estimated for a and b

[image]

Why does this occur? Shouldn't the behaviour of *smoothers a and b* be independent of *smoother c*, seeing as the plots obtained from plot(gam.object) are the PARTIAL residuals of the respective smoothers?

I'm using {mgcv} v. 1.8.16.

Comment: If you fix the regression coefficient of term in a linear model to something different from the MLE given the other terms in the model wouldn't you expect the other regression coefficients to change? Assuming that the variables you mention are not uncorrelated, variation in the response no longer modelled by `s(c)` can also be modelled by `s(a)` or `s(b)`, just as you'd expect in a linear model (note there is something wrong in the 2nd fig as the third plot has the y-axis labelled `s(b, 3)`).

Comment: Those are partial residuals in the plot but with the following definition: $\hat{\epsilon}^{\text{partial}}_{1i} = f_1(x_{1i}) + \hat{\epsilon}^{\text{p}}_{i}$ where $\hat{\epsilon}^{\text{p}}_{i}$ are the Pearson residuals of the fitted model, and $f_1(x_{1i})$ is the evaluation of the smooth term $f_1()$ at the observed values of the covariates. As such, because `f(c)` has changed in your example, the other terms are fitted to some of the remaining variation and hence we have different Pearson residuals and hence different partial residuals.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gavin Simpson. (Yes, that's a typo in the y-axis of the 3rd plot, well spotted.) Does the fact that the other smoothers/coefficients for `a` and `b` change with changing `s(c)` necessarily imply that the three predictors are correlated? (Strange as I checked for correlation as well as multicollinearity and the VIF <2 for all predictors.) Conversely, if they were not correlated, would smoothers `a` and `b` in theory show no change with changing `s(c)`? Your second commment makes sense...that the other terms adapt to accommodate.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) & you'll be able to edit your own questions. By the way, we already have an active user called 'gammer', so you might want to change your user name to avoid confusion.

Comment: @gammer *any* correlation will do between variables, even low correlation. Plus, with GAMs those correlations can be non-linear (so not captured by standard approaches). I didn't mean to suggest there was a collinearity (on concurvity as it is called in GAMs) issue, just that, unless your covariates were perfectly linearly and non-linearly (i.e. in some smooth way) uncorrelated this is expected behaviour and isn't restricted to GAMs --- linear models for example show the same behaviour.